# C++ HTTP GET request problems?

Tags: c++, http, tcp, winsock, get-request

I have written a program that sends a tcp request to a web address specified in the command line and prints the response. When I send thisget request to www.google.co.uk (or any website) I get nothing back :(

Could somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong as well as what a correct GET request to google should look like. Here's the code...

```
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

WSADATA wsaData;
int iResult;

//Initialize Winsock
iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
if(iResult != 0){
    printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
    return 1;
}

struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                *ptr = NULL,
                hints;

ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

#define DEFAULT_PORT "80"

//Resolve the server address and port
iResult = getaddrinfo(argv[1], DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
if(iResult != 0){
    printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n", iResult);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

//Attempt to connect to the first address returned by
//the call to getaddrinfo
ptr = result;

//Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype,
    ptr->ai_protocol);

if(ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET){
    printf("Error at socket(): %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

//Connect to server
iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
if(iResult == SOCKET_ERROR){
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
}

//Should really try the next address returned by getaddrinfo
//if the connect call failed
//But for this simple example we just free the resources
//returned by getaddrinfo and print an error message

freeaddrinfo(result);

if(ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET){
    printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512

int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

char *sendbuf = "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\n";
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];

//Send an initial buffer
iResult = send(ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0);
if(iResult == SOCKET_ERROR){
    printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

printf("Bytes Sent: %ld\n", iResult);

//shutdown the connection for sending since no more data will be sent
//the client can still use the ConenctSocket for receiving data
iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
if(iResult == SOCKET_ERROR){
    printf("shutdown failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

do {
    iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    if(iResult > 0){
        printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
        printf(recvbuf);
        printf("\n\n");
    } else if(iResult == 0){
        printf("Connection closed\n");
    } else {
        printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    }
} while(iResult > 0);

//cleanup
closesocket(ConnectSocket);
WSACleanup();

return 0;
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried get without a request to the page? I'm just wondering because how do you know if the index page is `index.html` or `index.html` or even `home.html`, etc, etc? So I would try a request like `GET HTTP/1.1`. And why do you close the connection before receiving the answer?

Comment: What does "I get nothing back" mean?  You get 0 bytes received, your program freezes or abruptly ends without ever printing anything!?

Comment: @ViteFalcon: it doesn't matter.  If the URL is invalid, the server would send a proper HTTP response anyways (redirect, page not found, etc.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possible reason is that the server is expecting more data before sending the response.

```
char *sendbuf = "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\n";
```

This should proabably be

```
char *sendbuf = "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
```

such that you tell the server not to expect more HTTP headers (each header is followed by a `\r\n` then an extra `\r\n` is added to end the request).

Basically, your HTTP request is incomplete.  There is at least one more header (`Host`) that must be provided.  Note that the server may (incorrectly) accept and incomplete request anyways.  If you want to start simple, copy a request sent by your browser (e.g. open the web debugger and look at the outgoing network requests).

Comment: It is going to expect more than that. An HTTP 1.1 request is REQUIRED to include a `Host` header as well, eg: `char *sendbug = "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: TheServerHostNameHere\r\n\r\n";`